# Java implementation of adjacency list

Tags: java, adjacency-list

I have a n*m matrix with integer value at each node and its an undirected graph. I want to build an adjacency list for it. How do I do that? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something? 2d array?

Comment: You mean an adjacency matrix?

Comment: Do you want an array where each position is a liked list?

Comment: yes, if the integers in original matrix mean the indexes of nodes where the edge is pointing to, then you are done. `int[][]`, where the first index is the index of the node and the values stored there are the destination nodes. If the topology is fixed, this is sufficient, if not, you may consider using some implementation of List.

Comment: This shows exactly no research. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) lists three possible implementation approaches alone.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple implementation for creating adjacency list.According to the problem:

There will be n linked lists each of variable size.

First Initialize an ArrayList of linked lists of integers:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> adj_list = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
```

Then simply add linked lists by repeating following code:

```
adj_list.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

If you are using it to represent graph,then no of linked lists=no of vertices.So you must repeat the above line n(no of vertices) times.

Say now you want to add numbers 3,4,5 to your first linked lists.Do the following:

```
adj_list.get(0).add(3);
adj_list.get(0).add(4);
adj_list.get(0).add(5);
```

It simply means there is an edge in your graph from vertex 0 to 3,4,5.

Comment: How should we go about if we want a weighted graph?

Comment: @MasterYushi here I found an example for weighted edges in graph using `javafx.util.Pair`: http://theoryofprogramming.com/adjacency-list-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

First your description seems to be of an adjacency matrix except you're saying `m` by `n`.  Adjacency matrices are always square, so we must assume `m==n`.  The matrix elements are the edge weights.

An adjacency list representation of a graph is (usually) an array `adj` of sets of pairs.  The set `adj[i]` contains pair `<j, w>` iff there is a directed edge `i--w-->j`, i.e. from vertex `i` to `j` with weight `w` in the represented graph.

With this definition, it's clear you must start with `n` empty adjacency sets `adj[i]` and then iterate over the matrix elements `m[i][j] = w`.  For each of these add `<j, w>` to `adj[i]`.

The java code for this is pretty trivial, so I won't write it.  The type for a graph represented with adjacency lists is something like `ArrayList<HashMap<Integer, Integer>> adjacencies`.  The pairs `<j,w> in adj[i]` are mappings `j -> w` stored in the hash table `adjacencies.get(i)`.  The code to create such an adjacency will be `adjacencies.get(i).put(j, w)`.

This method allows you to iterate over the vertices adjacent to `i` by iterating over keys in the hash table `adjacencies.get(i)`, look up the weight of a given edge `i--w-->j` with `w = adjacencies.get(i).get(j)`, and so on for all the usual graph operations.

Comment: Hi Gene,
The array which has the data for which I want to build an adjacency matrix is m*n where m!=n.

Comment: How many vertices does your graph have? `n` or `m`? An adjacency matrix is  supposed to be a square matrix. If you have `n x m` matrix, you surely are missing some edges.

Comment: ShivaKumar is exactly correct.  If you @Jw123 are using a rectangular matrix, then it is some kind of nonstandard representation of a graph, and you will have to explain what each element in your matrix represents before anyone can help you.  The secret to getting a good answer is always asking a good question.